# Add 2 numbers in assembly language and print the result

Tags: assembly, x86, addition, number-formatting, masm

I need help about how to add two numbers and then print the result.
Here is my code:

```
    .MODEL SMALL
    .STACK 200H
    .DATA
NUM1 DB 12
NUM2 DB 3
VAL  DB ?
MSG1 DB "The sum is : $"

    .CODE
BEGIN PROC 
      MOV AX, @DATA
      MOV DS, AX

      MOV AL, NUM1
      ADD AL, NUM2
      MOV VAL, AL
     
 

      LEA DX, MSG1
      MOV AH, 9
      INT 21H

      
      MOV AH, 2
      MOV DL, VAL
      INT 21H

      MOV AX, 4C00H
      INT 21H
BEGIN ENDP
      END BEGIN
```

I got an output that says:

```
The sum is 0
```

What is the error to my code?

Comment: *Which* assembly language?

Comment: You see it, it is masm, isn't ?

Comment: @icbytes: Not for me to say.

Answer (score 2):

By dividing the value constantly by 10 you'll get the single digits in the remainder - but in the "wrong" order (last to first). To print it in the "right" order (first to last) you can reverse them by `PUSH`ing and `POP`ing (keyword: LIFO = last in first out):

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 200H
.DATA
    NUM1 DB 12
    NUM2 DB 3
    VAL  DW ?
    MSG1 DB "The sum is : "
    DECIMAL  DB "00000$"

.CODE
BEGIN PROC
    MOV AX, @DATA
    MOV DS, AX

    XOR AX, AX
    MOV AL, NUM1
    ADD AL, NUM2
    ADC AH, 0
    MOV VAL, AX

    MOV AX, VAL
    CALL AX_to_DEC

    LEA DX, MSG1
    MOV AH, 9
    INT 21H

    MOV AX, 4C00H
    INT 21H
BEGIN ENDP

AX_to_DEC PROC
        mov bx, 10              ; divisor
        xor cx, cx              ; CX=0 (number of digits)

    First_Loop:
        xor dx, dx              ; Attention: DIV applies also DX!
        div bx                  ; DX:AX / BX = AX remainder: DX
        push dx                 ; LIFO
        inc cx                  ; increment number of digits
        test  ax, ax            ; AX = 0?
        jnz First_Loop          ; no: once more

        mov di, OFFSET DECIMAL  ; target string DECIMAL
    Second_Loop:
        pop ax                  ; get back pushed digit
        or ax, 00110000b        ; to ASCII
        mov byte ptr [di], al   ; save AL
        inc di                  ; DI points to next character in string DECIMAL
        loop Second_Loop        ; until there are no digits left

        mov byte ptr [di], '$'  ; End-of-string delimiter for INT 21 / FN 09h
        ret
AX_to_DEC ENDP

END BEGIN
```

Answer (score 1):

> I got an output that says
>
> ```
> The sum is 0
> ```

Since you were adding numbers 12 and 3 yielding 15, I would have expected your program to print: `The sum is : ☼`.

---

Assuming that the numbers involved are **unsigned (*)** byte-sized values, the biggest sum will arise from adding 255 to 255, which would produce 510. This value will not fit in your byte-size result variable *VAL*. You need to define *VAL* as a word-sized variable writing `VAL DW ?`.
The sum that you have stored in *VAL* is going to be a number in the range [0,510] and you can only visualize aka print it after you convert it to a string of text characters.

[Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904075/displaying-numbers-with-dos) has a full explanation about the conversion used in the below solution, albeit the code snippet that I present here today is somewhat different because it does not use the stack for intermediate storage. Anyway, the below solution is to be preferred!

```
    .MODEL SMALL
    .STACK 200H
    .DATA
NUM1 DB 12
NUM2 DB 3
VAL  DW ?
MSG  DB "The sum is : $"
BUF  DB ".....$"

    .CODE
BEGIN PROC 
  MOV  AX, @DATA
  MOV  DS, AX
  XOR  AX, AX
  MOV  AL, NUM1
  ADD  AL, NUM2
  ADC  AH, AH             ; In case there's a carry from the addition
  MOV  VAL, AX

  MOV  DX, OFFSET MSG
  MOV  AH, 09h            ; DOS.PrintString
  INT  21h

  MOV  AX, VAL
  MOV  BX, OFFSET BUF + 5 ; Points to where the terminating "$" is
  MOV  CX, 10             ; CONST
.More:
  XOR  DX, DX
  DIV  CX                 ; This divides DX:AX by 10 -> Quotient in AX
  DEC  BX                 ;                             Remainder in DX
  ADD  DL, "0"            ; Turn Remainder [0,9] into character ["0","9"]
  MOV  [BX], DL           ; Store in buffer starting from the end
  TEST AX, AX
  JNZ  .More              ; Continue for as long as Quotient is not zero

  MOV  DX, BX             ; Points to where the 1st character is
  MOV  AH, 09h            ; DOS.PrintString
  INT  21h

  MOV  AX, 4C00h          ; DOS.TerminateWithReturncode
  INT  21h
BEGIN ENDP
END BEGIN
```

**(*)** [Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904075/displaying-numbers-with-dos) also tells you how to deal with **signed** numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it like this, You will not see the number, You must get the ascii representating hexvalue s of the digits, which represent Your result. Very basic basics. Let me look for a link.

Here it is:
[How to convert from 4-bit hexadecimal to 7-bit ASCII?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054127/how-to-convert-from-4-bit-hexadecimal-to-7-bit-ascii)

Comment: any thoughts? really need help. newbie here

Answer (score -2):

```
section .data
    num1 db 10
    num2 db 20
    result db 0

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    ; Move the values of num1 and num2 into registers
    mov al, byte [num1]
    mov bl, byte [num2]

    ; Add the numbers
    add al, bl

    ; Move the result back to memory
    mov byte [result], al

    ; Exit the program
    mov eax, 1
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 0x80
```

Comment: This doesn't print the result. Also, it's a Linux program, not DOS like in the question.  See [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library? (itoa, integer to decimal ASCII string)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894) for how to do int -> string and make a write system-call in x86 Linux

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

_
section .data
num1 dd 5    ; Define the first number as a double word (4 bytes)
num2 dd 7    ; Define the second number as a double word
result db 0  ; Define a variable to store the result as a byte

section .text
global _start

_start:
; Load the first number (num1) into EAX
mov eax, [num1]

```
; Add the second number (num2) to EAX
add eax, [num2]

; Store the result in the result variable (byte)
mov [result], al

; Display the result on the screen
; For Linux, you can use the syscall to write to the console
mov edx, 1          ; Message length
mov ecx, result     ; Message pointer
mov ebx, 1          ; File descriptor (stdout)
mov eax, 4          ; syscall number for sys_write
int 0x80            ; Call the kernel

; Exit the program
mov eax, 1          ; syscall number for sys_exit
int 0x80            ; Call the kernel
```

Comment: The addition `5 + 7` produces 12. There's no way that outputting a 1-byte message will display the 2-character result! Also, please fix the formatting of the code: use triple backticks.